# нужно ли делать публичные методы для работы с каждой таблицей в классе по работе с бд?

Tags: java, база-данных, ооп

Я разрабатываю программу, работающую с базой данных. В базе 3 таблицы. Пользователь ни при каких обстоятельствах у меня не будет иметь возможность записать данные в какую то одну таблицу или в несколько таблиц, если он что то записывает - то информация записывается во все 3 таблицы. Для работы с базой данных я создаю интерфейс, который будет расширять мой класс для работы с базой данных. Вот как интерфейс выглядит сейчас:

```
public interface DBCooperatable {
    void saveData(Task);
    Task readData();
}
```

`Task` - Объект класса, который я записываю в бд. В классе `Task` у меня есть поле `String` и 2 одномерных массива. В первой таблицы я держу имена задач, а в двух других - одномерные массивы, которые с именем связываются по id задачи. А в классе, реализующем этот интерфейс у меня есть 3 приватных метода для записи и три приватных метода для чтения и в публичных методах идут вызовы этих приватных методов.

Вопрос у меня следующий - стоит ли мне предоставлять интерфейс для записи и чтения в каждую таблицу? Вот так он будет выглядеть:

```
public interface DBCooperatable {
    void saveDataInNameTable(String s);
    void saveDataInArr1Table(int[] arr);
    void saveDataInArr2Table(int[] arr);
    String readName();
    int[] readArr1();
    int[] readArr2();
}
```

Тогда в классе, реализующем интерфейс будет 6 публичных методов.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как лучше поступить?

Comment: Для каждой таблицы сделать свой класс, на основе общего. И добавить экземпляры этих классов в один общий класс как коллекцию таблиц или как отдельные поля|свойства. class Tables { Table1 table1, Table2 table2 }. Table1 extends Table { override save() ...}. Table { save(), read() }

Comment: @Suvitruf, проясните пожалуйста зачем так делать? Мне же не нужно данные в отдельные таблицы записывать? А тут даже специальные классы для этого выделяются

Comment: Какой-то философский вопрос. Все зависит от паттерна и удобства в определенной ситуации. Я например вобще не использую DAO, а все больше извращаю и переделываю Repository. Дабы его легко можно было достраивать, переделывать и иметь легкий доступ из каждого контроллера интерфейса JavaFX. Но при этом писанины там... ужас, как много!